# Is there a brute force approach to the defective chessboard problem?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, divide-and-conquer

I was looking for a computational problem for an assignment that specifies we need to show both the DnC approach and the brute force approach. I was very interested in "the defective chessboard" which is better explained in this question.
[Defective chessboard problem - looking for pseudocode algorithm (divide&conquer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896264/defective-chessboard-problem-looking-for-pseudocode-algorithm-divideconquer)

However, although it has been easy enough to find and understand the D&C approach, I have been struggling to find or create a brute force approach although I did find out that the naive approach has a time complexity of O(n^2).

> The defective chessboard problem is an interesting problem that is can be solved with a “divide and conquer” approach. The naive algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2).

Source: https://polaris000.github.io/blog/defective_chessboard

I was wondering if there is no brute force approach to this question, how is it that we have been able to find the time complexity, and if there is a brute force approach, I would like some guidance on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There do exist brute force approaches to this problem.

For example you could have a function that placed a trionimo covering the first available empty square in all possible orientations, and then called itself recursively to see if there was a solution to filling in the remaining holes.

However, this would have exponential complexity as it would need to backtrack whenever it became impossible to place a trionimo.

I think the comment about "the naive algorithm" refers to the fact that the described implementation of the divide and conquer algorithm would have O(n^2) complexity (because O(n^2) trionimos are placed one at a time).

A more sophisticated implementation of this divide and conquer algorithm could spot that most of the subproblems are identical (solving a square with a single square missing at a corner), so the answer to this subproblem could be cached and reused for lower computational complexity.